# EWS Managed Api - Retrieve calendar items only once

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, outlook-calendar

I've got a windows service to read calendar items from Exchange and store them in my application's DB against each user.
Now I wonder what is the best way to mark an item on Exchange to not be retrieved in the next service run after storing it?

I tried to add an extended property to the calendar item and set it's value and then search based on it's value each time:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(60);
const int NUM_APPTS = 60;    
// Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

Guid myPropertyId = new Guid("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}");
ExtendedPropertyDefinition myExtendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(myPropertyId, "SyncFlag", MapiPropertyType.Boolean);

// Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, end time and the extended property.
 cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Location, myExtendedProperty);

// Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, DateTime.Now));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.End, DateTime.Now.AddDays(60)));

searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsNotEqualTo(myExtendedProperty, true)); //Do not fetch already marked calendar items

SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilterCollection);

FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, searchFilter, cView);
```

Searching calendar items using this code throws this exception:

> *Restrictions and sort order may not be specified for a CalendarView.*

And I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it either. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to this is to use the [`SyncFolderItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693003(v=exchg.80).aspx) method. It will return the items that were changed since the last call.  All you have to do is save a synchronization "cookie" between each call.

You should also filter out the appointment items that were created since your last call.

This below code snippet should do the trick.

```
static private void GetChangedItems()
{
    // Path to cookie
    string syncStateFileName = @"c:\temp\ewssyncstate.txt";

    try
    {
        var service = GetServiceAP();
        bool moreChangesAvailable = false;

        do
        {
            string syncState = null;


            if (File.Exists(syncStateFileName))
            {
                // Read cookie
                syncState = File.ReadAllText(syncStateFileName);
            }

            ChangeCollection<ItemChange> icc = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null, 10, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, syncState);

            if (icc.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no item changes to synchronize.");
            }
            else
            {
                syncState = icc.SyncState;

                // Save cookie
                File.WriteAllText(syncStateFileName, syncState);

                moreChangesAvailable = icc.MoreChangesAvailable;

                // Only get appointments that were created since last call
                var createdItems = icc
                    .Where(i => i.ChangeType == ChangeType.Create)
                    .Select(i => i.Item as Appointment)
                    ;

                if (createdItems.Any())
                {
                    service.LoadPropertiesForItems(createdItems, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

                    foreach (Appointment appointment in createdItems)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(appointment.Subject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (moreChangesAvailable);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```